# What is this dashed bounding box left where there is no geometry?

Tags: mesh, objects

I have created a house using a plane. Then I decided to redo the house. 
I kept the old house to see the dimensions, and after re-doing the house, I deleted the old house.
However, Blender still shows the box of the old house.

[image]

Why is that so and how can I delete this artifact? There are no vertices in the old house anymore, so I am not sure why Blender still shows this box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those dashed lines normally represent the object's texture space when *Texture Space* is enabled in *Properties > Object > Display*:

[image]

You might have accidentally pressed <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> at some point, which is used for translating the texture space. As a side effect it enables texture space display as in the screenshot above.

If you disable texture space display, then they should go away.